# I did 'ifdown eth0' and...I can't connect my instance

Tags: ubuntu, eth0

I should have run `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0`, but I just ran `ifdown eth0`.
Can I connect to my instance and run `ifup eth0`? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything to do other than rebooting the machine or connect to the console...

Answer (score 0):

Once you have shut down the Ethernet interface the only way to bring it back online is either explicitly by running ifup  on the console or rebooting the instance.

There is no remote way to bring up an interface that has been shut down.

(Assuming this is a single if device, which seems fair given if another up if existed you would already have connected via it and run if up.)